# 403 (Forbidden) Error When Loading an Image

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-403

I am developing a website using PHP and MySql. I hosted the same website in 2 different servers (one for testing purposes), and I tried to mount image directory to test server. I can see the mounted directory and files in both servers. But test website doesn't show any images under this mounted directory. Naturally I did a console check to see what the problem is, and it says 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)'

Comment: Might be an issue with permissions. Can you check the image permissions ?

Comment: This is clearly a permissions problem. Check the directory's settings.

Comment: Yes, its clearly permission issue. So i checked permission and its 755. But i don't understand then how it shows in one website.

Comment: Do you have any differences in your web server (Apache?) or any file based configurations (`.htaccess` files) between the two hosts? Sounds like a web server is preventing access rather than the root FS. I also don't think this is related to PHP or MySQL so suggest you remove the tags and add your web server in.